# How to streamline json file manipulation in python

Tags: python, json

My company is very strict on adhering to pydocstyle. I'm running up against the line limit trying to modify these values nested in a json file.

```
    Rem_Conf['RemediationConfigurations'][0]['Parameters']['AutomationAssumeRole']['StaticValue']['Values'][0] = rolearn
    Rem_Conf['RemediationConfigurations'][0]['Parameters']['GranteeId']['StaticValue']['Values'][0] = canid
    Rem_Conf['RemediationConfigurations'][0]['Parameters']['TargetBucket']['StaticValue']['Values'][0] = targetbucket
```

How I can compress this to meet the 79 character pydocstyle limit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to replace the inline keys with short named variables

```
cfg='RemediationConfigurations'
params='Parameters'
role='AutomationAssumeRole'
sval='StaticValue'
val='Values'
guid='GranteeId'
tbuk='TargetBucket'
Rem_Conf[cfg][0][params][role][sval][val][0] = rolearn
Rem_Conf[cfg][0][params][guid][sval][val][0] = canid
Rem_Conf[cfg][0][params][tbuk][sval][val][0] = targetbucket
```

Here the longest line is `60` chars and it makes the pattern of values very clear to a reader

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the lines in parentheses, like below. Of course, feel free to play around with the formatting. This is what the `black` formatter outputs.

```py
(
    Rem_Conf["RemediationConfigurations"][0]["Parameters"]["AutomationAssumeRole"][
        "StaticValue"
    ]["Values"][0]
) = rolearn
(
    Rem_Conf["RemediationConfigurations"][0]["Parameters"]["GranteeId"]["StaticValue"][
        "Values"
    ][0]
) = canid
(
    Rem_Conf["RemediationConfigurations"][0]["Parameters"]["TargetBucket"][
        "StaticValue"
    ]["Values"][0]
) = targetbucket
```

IMHO, this would be a readable format:

```py
(Rem_Conf
    ["RemediationConfigurations"]
    [0]
    ["Parameters"]
    ["AutomationAssumeRole"]
    ["StaticValue"]
    ["Values"]
    [0]
) = rolearn
```

This is what the `black` python formatter outputs on your original code:

```py
Rem_Conf["RemediationConfigurations"][0]["Parameters"]["AutomationAssumeRole"][
    "StaticValue"
]["Values"][0] = rolearn
Rem_Conf["RemediationConfigurations"][0]["Parameters"]["GranteeId"]["StaticValue"][
    "Values"
][0] = canid
Rem_Conf["RemediationConfigurations"][0]["Parameters"]["TargetBucket"]["StaticValue"][
    "Values"
][0] = targetbucket
```

Answer (score 2):

Other answers are even better, just wanted to add that at the very least you could use backslashes like that:

```py
Rem_Conf['RemediationConfigurations'][0]['Parameters'] \
            ['AutomationAssumeRole']['StaticValue']['Values'][0] = rolearn
Rem_Conf['RemediationConfigurations'][0]['Parameters'] \
            ['GranteeId']['StaticValue']['Values'][0] = canid
Rem_Conf['RemediationConfigurations'][0]['Parameters'] \
            ['TargetBucket']['StaticValue']['Values'][0] = targetbucket
```

Python documentation states the following:

> ### 2.1.5. Explicit line joining
>
> Two or more physical lines may be joined into logical lines using
>   backslash characters (`\`), as follows: when a physical line ends in a
>   backslash that is not part of a string literal or comment, it is
>   joined with the following forming a single logical line, deleting the
>   backslash and the following end-of-line character.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply use an intermediate value:

```
Parameters = Rem_Conf['RemediationConfigurations'][0]['Parameters']
Parameters['AutomationAssumeRole']['StaticValue']['Values'][0] = rolearn
Parameters['GranteeId']['StaticValue']['Values'][0] = canid
Parameters['TargetBucket']['StaticValue']['Values'][0] = targetbucket
```